# What causes the "ctx[1] is not a function" error in this small Svelte app?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am working on a small to-do app with Svelte. I list 10 todos from jsonplaceholder.

I have this in App.svelte:

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from "svelte";
    import Header from './Header.svelte';
    import ToDoList from './ToDoList.svelte';
    import Footer from './Footer.svelte';
    const apiURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos";
    const limit = 10;
    let todos = [];
    export let unsolvedTodos = [];
    
    onMount(() => {
        getTodos();
    });
    
    const getTodos = () => {
        fetch(`${apiURL}?&_limit=${limit}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => todos = data)
        .then(getUnsolvedTodos);
    }
    
    const getUnsolvedTodos = () => {
        unsolvedTodos = todos.filter(todo => {
            return todo.completed === false;
        })
    }

    const deleteTodo = (todo) => {
        let itemIdx = todos.findIndex(x => x == todo);
        todos.splice(itemIdx, 1);
        todos = todos;
  }
</script>

<div class="app-wrapper">
  <div id="toDoApp">
        <Header />
    <ToDoList todos={todos} />
    <Footer />
  </div>
</div>
```

In ToDoList.app:

```
<script>
    import TodoItem from './TodoItem.svelte';
    export let todos;
    let deleteTodo;
</script>

{#if todos.length > 0}
  <ul class="todo-list">
    {#each todos as todo, index}
        <TodoItem {todo} on:deleteTodo = {deleteTodo(todo)} />
    {/each}
  </ul>
{/if}
```

In TodoItem.svelte:

```
<script>
    import {createEventDispatcher} from 'svelte';
    import { fade, fly } from 'svelte/transition';
    import { flip } from 'svelte/animate';
    export let todo;
    
    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
    const Delete = () => dispatch("deleteTodo", todo);
</script>

<li transition:fly="{{x:-100, duration:200}}">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="{todo.completed}" />
    <span class="title {todo.completed ? 'done' : ''}">{todo.title}</span>
    <button on:click="{Delete}"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</li>
```

I must be missing something because I get the error `ctx[1] is not a function` as can be seen in this **[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/12cb6530a9bd46729751762e9979b610?version=3.38.2)**.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `ToDoList.svelte` you are calling `deleteTodo(todo)` but `deleteTodo` is undefined. Svelte should really throw a better error message here...

Edit:

Also, if you assign an event handler, you want to pass in a reference to a function like `on:deleteTodo = {() => deleteTodo(todo)}` or `on:deleteTodo = {deleteTodo}` and not call the function directly.

Comment: I have `let deleteTodo` in ToDoList.svelte, at the top. I also have `<TodoItem {todo} on:deleteTodo = {deleteTodo(todo)} />`. See **[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/12cb6530a9bd46729751762e9979b610?version=3.38.2)**.

Comment: You have `let deleteTodo` but that is a variable not a function definition so nothing happens when you call it like a function. Also as Leander said you're calling it wrong if you want to pass an argument to the function using an event handler, it won't work as `{function(arg)}` you need `{()=> function(arg)}`. This answer is correct.

Comment: Maybe you want to pass the `deleteTodo` function which is declared in `App.svelte` to `ToDoList`. so `let deleteTodo;` has to become `export let deleteTodo;`and `<ToDoList todos={todos} />` can become `<ToDoList todos={todos} deleteTodo={deleteTodo} />` or the shorthand `<ToDoList {todos} {deleteTodo} />`. It's not the best pattern to follow but it works